# asynchronous only when there are less data

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, system.reactive, parallel.foreach

I am reading azure tables' data - around 5k tables and collects different metrics and save them back to some other azure tables, everything in a asynchronous way. The problem I am facing is when there are huge data which can happen occasionally, application starts hanging. The same code is working fine with less data. The steps I am doing (all of them are asynchronous using Rx, async and await)  are

1. Read all the table names from Azure
2. Read all the tables previous metric data (1 & 2 are in parallel - `Task.WhenAll`)
3. Get data from each table, process and save (`Task.WhenAll`)

what I want is, use asynchronousy till it doesn't make my application hanging. If there are more data than what can be handled, it should not read any more table's data instead focus on completing the available data processing.

Does `Parallel.ForEach` takes care of that?

The code: **edited as per [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary)**, Still not working for all the tables. whereas it is working for 500 tables,

I think it is the amount of data that brings the app (console app) to a standstill rather than the number of threads. (One thread may end up retrieving million rows, in thousands and each thousand is passed to a method and its count is added to dictionary hence can be garbage collected when there is a need for more memory) or is it the way I have implemented `Semaphoreslim` that is wrong?

```
public async Task CalculateMetricsForAllTablesAsync()
{
    var allWizardTableNamesTask = GetAllWizardTableNamesAsync();
    var allTablesNamesWithLastRunTimeTask = GetAllTableNamesWithLastRunTimeAsync();

    await Task.WhenAll(allWizardTableNamesTask, allTablesNamesWithLastRunTimeTask).ConfigureAwait(false);

    var allWizardTableNames = allWizardTableNamesTask.Result;
    var allTablesNamesWithLastRunTime = allTablesNamesWithLastRunTimeTask.Result;

    var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(10);
    var concurrentTableProcessingTasks = new ConcurrentStack<Task>();

    foreach (var tname in allWizardTableNames)
    {
        await throttler.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
           concurrentTableProcessingTasks.Push(ProcessTableDataAsync(tname, getTableNameWithLastRunTime(tname)));
        }
        finally
        {
            throttler.Release();
         }
     }

     await Task.WhenAll(concurrentTableProcessingTasks).ConfigureAwait(false);

}

private async Task ProcessTableDataAsync(string tableName, Tuple<string, string> matchingTable)
{
    var tableDataRetrieved = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    var metricCountsForEachDay = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Tuple<int, int>>();

    _fromATS.GetTableDataAsync<DynamicTableEntity>(tableName, GetFilter(matchingTable))
        .Subscribe(entities => ProcessWizardDataChunk(metricCountsForEachDay, entities), () => tableDataRetrieved.TrySetResult(true));

    await tableDataRetrieved.Task;
    await SaveMetricDataAsync(tableName, metricCountsForEachDay).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: You need to show us your code.

Comment: Also you should either stick to Rx or TPL/async/await. One or the other, not both. It's very easy to cause deadlocks when you mix them. Personally I'd go with Rx for what you're doing.

Comment: I don't think it is deadlock, when I debug and stop at break point, other threads are doing work and there is less pressure on memory as I have stopped processing further threads

Comment: Still, it's a bad idea to mix Rx & TPL. Where's the Rx code you are using?

Comment: Mixing Rx and `async` is fine. In fact, Rx permits you to `await` a sequence and has several operators designed specifically for `await` (e.g., `LastAsync`).

Comment: @StephenCleary - It really depends how you move between the two. If you start "rolling your own operators" it can be a nightmare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `async` is wrapping Rx, I'd recommend throttling at the `async` level. You can do this by defining a `SemaphoreSlim` and wrapping your method logic within a `WaitAsync`/`Release`.

Alternatively, consider TPL Dataflow. Dataflow has built-in options for throttling (`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`), and also interoperates naturally with `async` and Rx.

Comment: Does controlling number of threads solve the amount of data? Even few threads could bring more data from multiple tables right?

Comment: The throttling will restrict the number of tasks that are doing the processing. Your updated code is not applying the throttling correctly (it's only throttling the *start* of `ProcessTableDataAsync` and adding the task to the stack). Instead, you should have all the code in `ProcessTableDataAsync` inside the `try`.

Comment: couldn't get throttling correct with `Semaphoreslim`. Went with `TPL Dataflow`. Composing asynchronous code with `TPL Dataflow` became easy. With limited number of tables I am seeing the visible perf improvement. Going to test for all the tables.